# If variable.onclick is true then execute command

Tags: jquery, button, onclick

I want to create dynamic buttons for my webpage. I am using the below code for that:

```js
var x = ["one","two","three"];
var btn = [];
var live;
        
$(document).ready(function() {
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
btn[i] = document.createElement("BUTTON");
var t = document.createTextNode(x[i]);
btn[i].appendChild(t);
btn[i].onclick = function() {
// $(location).attr('href', "tickets.html");
return false;
        };
$('#savedGames').append(btn[i]); 
$('#savedGames').append('\r\n');
    }
    });
```

```html
<h1>SAVED GAMES</h1>
<div id='savedGames'></div>
```

The above command helps me create the no. of buttons I want. However, I also want that whichever button I click its record gets captured in a variable.

For example:
if 2nd button is clicked then alert that button no. "2" (or "1" as per counting) has been clicked. Something like this:

```
for(i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
if(btn[i].clicked == true) {
alert(i);
}
}
```

However, the above code does not work. It automatically assumes the value to be true and alert message keeps appearing continuously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the button number it is enough to get the index of button text (refer to [textContent property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)) and add the [event parameter to your handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick):

```js
var x = ["one","two","three"];
var btn = [];
var live;
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    btn[i] = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    var t = document.createTextNode(x[i]);
    btn[i].appendChild(t);
    btn[i].onclick = function (e) {
        var noBtn = x.indexOf(e.target.textContent) + 1;
        console.log('button no. "' + noBtn + '" has been clicked.');
        return false;
    };
    $('#savedGames').append(btn[i]);
    $('#savedGames').append('\r\n');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>SAVED GAMES</h1>
<div id='savedGames'></div>
```

A full jQuery implementation is:

```js
var x = ["one","two","three"];
$.each(x, function(index, element) {
    $('<button/>', {
        text: element,
        'click': function (e) {
            var noBtn = x.indexOf(e.target.textContent) + 1;
            console.log('button no. "' + noBtn + '" has been clicked.');
            return false;
        }
    }).add('<span/>', {text: '\r\n'}).appendTo('#savedGames');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<h1>SAVED GAMES</h1>
<div id='savedGames'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using jQuery, why not use it for button generation as well? If you want to do something on button click event then you can add a class and data value to the button while creating:

```
btn[i] = "<button class='count-button-class' data-val="+x[i]+"></button>";
```

Then add the part you want to be executed on button click to the dynamically created button like this:

```
$(document).on("click", "button.count-button-class", function () {
    alert($(this).data('val'));
});
```